# Why impala-jdbc throws exception when casting from BigDecimal to DECIMAL?

Tags: jdbc, cloudera, impala, apache-kudu

I'm writing to a Kudu table using impala-jdbc 2.6.4.1005.

I got this error when inserting a BigDecimal with value 7896163500 to DECIMAL(20,2).

```
[Cloudera][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500051) ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 0, SQL state: TStatus(statusCode:ERROR_STATUS, sqlState:HY000, errorMessage:AnalysisException: Possible loss of precision for target table 'ST.RFQ_SPOT'.
Expression '7896163500' (type: BIGINT) would need to be cast to DECIMAL(20,2) for column 'req_amount'
```

However, the value I'm inserting would fit also in a DECIMAL(12,2).
I cannot understand why I get this error from the driver.

If I define the column as DECIMAL(30,2) it works correctly.

In addition, if I try to manually make the cast, I get the result as expected:

```
select cast (cast(7896163500 as BIGINT) as DECIMAL(12,2))
1   7896163500.00
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected event.

In Impala, by default - If you specify a value such as 7896163500 to go into a DECIMAL column, Impala checks if the column has enough precision to represent the largest value of that integer type, and raises an error if not.

Here 7896163500 is a BIGINT and BIGINT's maximum storage is 8 Bytes. Since we have 2 fractional digits here, you see the below error,

```
Expression '7896163500' (type: BIGINT) would need to be cast to DECIMAL(20,2) for column 'req_amount'
```

Therefore, use an expression like `(cast(7896163500 as BIGINT)` as `DECIMAL(12,2))` for DECIMAL columns as you have already done to insert the details. Hope this helps!

For more: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/impala_decimal.html